# Error webpack dev server when using yarn workspaces

Tags: webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I got an error "`webpack-dev-server error cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config/config-yargs`'" when installing webpack, webpack-cli and webpack-dev-server  in a yarn workspace. 
Doesn't have this issue when installing them in a repo.

I checked the node_modules in the root and in the child. It appears that this config/config-yargs file is installed in the node_module of the **CHILD** but not in the **ROOT** one.

I have to copy it manually from child to root to make this works.

Is there a way to install this correctly ?

**My root package.json :**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/server",
        "packages/front", <-- webpack has been installed her
    ],
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

**part of child package.json**

```
{
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5",
        "webpack": "^4.41.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const rules = [
    {
        test: /\.(tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    },
];
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/examples/index.tsx",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    module: { rules },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./",
        port: 5000,
        historyApiFallback: true, 
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "react typescript babel webpack boilerplate",
            template: "index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: It seems that Yarn's deduping model applied in workspaces breaks the thing. Probably PNPM will do this job better, but it also has its own restrictions (it based on symlinks, so some software may not work, angular's ngcc as an example)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use embedded devServer with `webpack serve` command, read about it here

https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server

You might have another problem with **workspaces** and the solution is **nohoist**, read about it here

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/

Nohoist for me was not working until I figured out it should be used on **root package.json** and not in child, here is the version that worked for me

```
"workspaces": {
"packages": [
  "package-1",
  "package-2",
],
"nohoist": [
  "**/webpack",
  "**/webpack/**",
  "**/webpack-dev-server",
  "**/webpack-dev-server/**",
  "**/@webpack-cli",
  "**/@webpack-cli/**",
  "**/webpack-cli",
  "**/webpack-cli/**"
]
},
```

You might also want to delete **node_modules** as usual :)